# how to output html to a file with xmllint?

Tags: files, scripting, xml, html, xmllint

How do I get `xmllint` to output [to a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9010920/262852) file?

```
thufir@dur:~/xmllint$ 
thufir@dur:~/xmllint$ xmllint --html http://www.skynet.be/nieuws-sport/weer/mijn-weer?cityId=6450  --xpath '//div[@class = "tides"]' - 2>/dev/null
<div class="tides">
            <div class="weather-sprite icon  st_nl" title="Marées Oostende"></div>
            <p>Hoogtij: <strong>10:28</strong>  <strong>23:11</strong></p>
            <p>Laagtij: <strong>04:44</strong>  <strong>17:13</strong></p>
            <div class="weather-sprite icon  anv_nl clearFlt" title="Marées Anvers"></div>
            <p>Hoogtij: <strong>00:41</strong>  <strong>13:06</strong></p>
            <p>Laagtij: <strong>07:11</strong>  <strong>07:11</strong></p>
        </div><div class="tides">
            <div class="weather-sprite icon  st_nl" title="Marées Oostende"></div>
            <p>Hoogtij: <strong>11:31</strong>  <strong></strong></p>
            <p>Laagtij: <strong>05:48</strong>  <strong>18:10</strong></p>
            <div class="weather-sprite icon  anv_nl clearFlt" title="Marées Anvers"></div>
            <p>Hoogtij: <strong>01:42</strong>  <strong>14:02</strong></p>
            <p>Laagtij: <strong>08:20</strong>  <strong>08:20</strong></p>
        </div>
^C
thufir@dur:~/xmllint$
```

As it hangs, it has to be killed.  The fine manual:

> ```
>    --output FILE
>        Define a file path where xmllint will save the result of parsing.
>        Usually the programs build a tree and save it on stdout, with this
>        option the result XML instance will be saved onto a file.
> ```

but can't get that working.  I don't need any output to the console at all, only interested in the file creation.  *This is to tidy up the `html` for processing by `saxon`.*

Comment: Hi, it's not what you want, but it could be useful. The tool I use is [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) and the command is `curl "http://www.skynet.be/nieuws-sport/weer/mijn-weer?cityId=6450" | pup 'div.tides' >out.html'

Answer (score 3):

I think when using the `--html` option in [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), some other options are ignored, such as `--format` and `--output`. (Tried it with [`libxml2`](http://xmlsoft.org/) v2.9.4 that came with macOS High Sierra, and with v2.9.10 from [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libxml2).)

Instead, to write `xmllint`'s output to a file, you can redirect its standard output stream, by using the `>` ("greater-than") redirection operator.

## Syntax

```
xmllint --html input.html > output.html
```

## Example

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//p" http://example.com > output.html 2>/dev/null
```

Options/arguments:

- `--html` — parse the input as HTML.
- `--xpath "//p"` — XPath query selecting all `<p>` tags from the input.
- `http://example.com` — input file, in this case downloaded directly from the specified URL.
- `> output.html` — redirect standard output stream (stdout) to the specified file.
- `2>/dev/null` — optional: suppress standard error stream (stderr) from the terminal by redirecting it to the null device (`/dev/null`).

(See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237) for a nice cheat sheet of output/error redirection.)

## HTTPS

Note that `xmllint` does not appear to support HTTPS at this time (as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602855/xmllint-doesnt-work-with-https-warning-failed-to-load-external-entity)).  Instead, you could use another utility like [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download the file first, then pipe it to `xmllint`'s standard input, by using the `|` ("pipe"/"vertical bar") control operator, and `-` ("hyphen/minus") for `xmllint`'s file argument.

```
curl --silent "https://example.com" | xmllint --html --xpath "//p" - > output.html 2>/dev/null
```

Options/arguments:

- `--silent` or `-s` — suppress `curl` progress/error messages (which might otherwise get processed by `xmllint`'s parser).
- `"https://example.com"` — input file that `curl` will download (over HTTPS, in this case) and pass to `xmllint`.  (Use quotes if the URL contains `&` or other special characters.)
- `|` — pipe the prior command's standard output (`curl`) to the next command's standard input (`xmllint`).
- `--html` — parse `xmllint`'s input as HTML.
- `--xpath "//p"` — XPath query selecting all `<p>` tags from the input.
- `-` — `xmllint` gets its input from the standard input stream (stdin) (i.e. from `curl`'s output) instead of from a file or URL.
- `> output.html` — redirect `xmllint`'s standard output stream (stdout) to the specified file.
- `2>/dev/null` — optional: suppress `xmllint`'s standard error stream (stderr) from the terminal by redirecting it to the null device (`/dev/null`).

(See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/407444) for a nice list of control/redirection operators.)